# Embed "cat file" in CURL data

Tags: shell-script, curl

I would like to cat the contents of a `file.txt` and use this as part of the `--data` field in my curl query.

I tried:

```
curl ... --data '{ "file_content":[" $(cat file.txt) ", ...]}"' ...
```

but that passes the string `$(cat file.txt)` to the server rather than interpreting it before sending.

I also tried:

```
curl ... --data '{ "file_content":[" `cat file.txt` ", ...]}"' ...
```

Again, the passes the string as it is instead of interpreting it.

Comment: so, if you do indeed have single-quotes around the data portion, you'll need to end & restart them around the $(cat file.txt) portion in order for that to expand. As it stands now, the entire data portion is quote off to prevent shell expansion & substition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably wouldn't need 3 of those backslashes if you can remove the shell from the equation. Luckily, you can:

```sh
{   printf '{ "file_content":["'
    cat file.txt
    printf '", ...]}"'
}|  curl ... --data-binary @-
```

Look at `man curl`. I suggest paying close attention to the differences between `--data-ascii` *(which is what `-d` means)*, `--data-binary`, and `--data-urlencoded`.

Comment: Perhaps this could updated to be more robust by using a tool that is aware of JSON, such as jq? Something like `jq --null-input --arg contents "$(<file.txt)" '{ file_content: [$contents, ...]}' | curl ...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -d "$(cat /path/to/my/file.txt)" -X POST http://<your_base_URL>/api/v1/endpoint
```

Tested this one and it works. If you want to put everything against the file_content key, you have to be careful with the quoting, as the file you cat may have any number of quotes inside it.